# Image and comment uploading

Tags: php, image

```
@$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
@$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
@$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

$user_post = $_POST['string']
```

$user_post is mandatory for proceeding while, image uploading is not compulsory to proceed further, i have tried various methods but

```
$image_size === false
```

takes into account an empty image file and also the wrong image file being upload. I cant check if the image selected is empty or the image file selected is incorrect separately.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: Many people would have solution for this, only if the problem itself was known / explained better. As a side note, get rid of those `@` and `addslashes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image upload is optionally and you want to check if the user has uploaded an image or not you can use the array part `$_FILES['image']['error']`  this part gives you the errorcode of the file.

When this part has the value **4** then no file has been uploade. You can check for that, when moving the file.

Src: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

I hope this is what you wanted. If not please clarify your question.